# Submit options page input values with decimals

Tags: settings-api

I have an Options page for my plugin using Settings API. I want to submit the settings values with two places after decimals.

Right now when I submit a number let's say: `35.00` it submits as `35`. How can I submit with `.00` by default. If the number is `15.20`, it saves as `15.2` but I would like it to be saved as `15.20`.

How can I do this?